# Reverse geom_density order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# OUR REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_density(bins = 50, stat = "bin", alpha = 0.3)
```

Above is a nice density plot using *count* instead of *density*. Just like I want, *almost*.

I also want to reverse the order of the diamond `cut` factor, so the `ideal` factor moves to the back of the plot and the `fair` factor moves to the front. None of my proposed solutions from other StackOverflow questions work. What is the correct solution?

```
# DOESNT APPEAR TO CHANGE ANYTHING
library(forcats)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut), fct_rev(cut)) +
  geom_density(bins = 50, stat = "bin", alpha = 0.3)

#JUST SCREWS UP THE Y SCALE
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_density(bins = 50, stat = "bin", alpha = 0.3) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(diamonds$cut)))

# JUST TOTALLY WRONG
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_density(
    bins = 50, stat = "bin", 
    alpha = 0.3, 
    position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you apply `fct_rev()` within `aes()`, you should get the desired output.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = fct_rev(cut))) +
  geom_density(bins = 50, stat = "bin", alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]